# gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable error: Wrong JPEG library version: library is 80, caller expects 62

Tags: apache-2.2, php, gd

As the title says, I'm getting the above error in my Apache log files when calling

```
imagecreatefromjpeg()
```

in PHP.

Running:

```
apt-get install libjpeg62-dev
```

Tells me that it is already at the latest version.

```
libjpeg.so.62
```

Also exists in /usr/lib

(Running Ubuntu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that /usr/lib/libjpeg.so.62 actually is the file you think it is (ie not been overwritten by something/someone)
Something like:
for f in `find . -type f -name "*jpeg*"` ; do md5sum $f | uniq ; done
would be a good start (you seem to have another version of libjpeg, thus the error)

Answer (score 0):

Try to find the gd.so file used by php for the gd functions (if it is installed with ubuntu packages it should be in /usr/lib/php5/20060613) and type:

```
ldd gd.so
```

you will see all shared libraries that the object is using:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff8f7ed000)
libgd.so.2 => /usr/lib/libgd.so.2 (0x00007f813cfcc000)
libt1.so.5 => /usr/lib/libt1.so.5 (0x00007f813cd6f000)
libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f813caea000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f813c7de000)
libXpm.so.4 => /usr/lib/libXpm.so.4 (0x00007f813c5cd000)
libpng12.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpng12.so.0 (0x00007f813c3a7000)
libz.so.1 => /usr/lib/libz.so.1 (0x00007f813c190000)
libjpeg.so.62 => /usr/lib/libjpeg.so.62 (0x00007f813bf6e000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f813bc1a000)
libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007f813b9e5000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007f813b762000)
libxcb-xlib.so.0 => /usr/lib/libxcb-xlib.so.0 (0x00007f813b560000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f813b344000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f813b140000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f813d43a000)
libexpat.so.1 => /usr/lib/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f813af16000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f813ad14000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f813ab0f000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f813a8f2000)
```

Check if libjpeg heads to the right version. If not, you should figure out why (hint LIBRARY_PATH)

Comment: The relevant line from that output on my server:

        libjpeg.so.62 => /usr/lib/libjpeg.so.62 (0x00007f1abecb5000)

Comment: this looks good. So either your php isn't using this gd.so or apache has a different load path which has the 80 version before the 62.

Comment: Any pointers as to where to look next?